# Warning when reloading a module in Python and PyCharm 2020.2

Tags: python, pycharm, reload

After updating to PyCharm 2020.2, the following piece of code:

```
import DataSets
import importlib

importlib.reload( DataSets )
```

issues the warning `Expected type 'ModuleType', got 'DataSets.py' instead` for the last statement.  Everything works as expected, and I am pretty sure that `DataSets` is a module.  Can anyone please let me know why I am getting this warning and how I can get rid of it?

My dev environment is based on Python 3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like this issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36062, feel free to vote (thumbs up near the title)